# What is going Wrong?

Tags: jquery

i want to submit form through jquery. so if there is error then form will not submit and if every thing is right then the form is submit.

```
cForm.bind("submit", function(e){
     if(validateName(e, cinputName) & validateEmail(e, cinputEmail) & validateMessage(e, cinputMessage)) { 
        ajaxSend(cForm, cresponseText, cloadingImage);
                return true;
        };
       else
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Where is the form? what is the code of the `validate` functions? And, what errors are thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the example above, you don't even need the `else` statement. I've removed that and the extra `;` in there:

```
cForm.bind("submit", function(e) {
    if (validateName(e, cinputName) & validateEmail(e, cinputEmail) & validateMessage(e, cinputMessage)) {
        ajaxSend(cForm, cresponseText, cloadingImage);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an extra `;` before the `else`

Comment: Yes, Now its right.. actually i want to use this code to submit the form using ajax and display message. and if error then error is display...

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested this, but remove the semicolon before the "else", it doesn't look right!

Answer (score 1):

This is why we have indentation and coding standards, to signify the seperation of programming:

clean your code up to help find errors:

```
cForm.bind("submit", function(e)
{
    if(validateName(e, cinputName) && validateEmail(e, cinputEmail) && validateMessage(e, cinputMessage))
    {
        ajaxSend(cForm, cresponseText, cloadingImage);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

You were missing up your conditional brackets by omitting the one after the false keyword, you were also using single `&` signs where as its `&&`.

Comment: Yes you are right, but when enclose && then it will show only the first one error. and by single it working fine.

Comment: The thing is, it's working, its just that your functions are returing a falsy value, using the `&` is for shifting binary values around, there nothing to do with logical interpretations such as true and false, for example `1 ^ 1 & 2` would evaluate to 1, this is not 1 as in true.